# How to add 2 collections in Firestore using React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add 2 collections in Firestore in React Native. 
Like `JOIN` can be used to add 2 tables. Is there any alternative for `JOIN` in Firestore to add collections?

[image]

[image]

I want to add these 2 collections **users** and **users_2**
How can I do this? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing it is not possible to query documents across collections in Firestore (it is apparently a feature that is on the roadmap however, see this recent blog post https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-cloud-firestore-general-availability-and-updates -see bullet point "More features coming soon"-).

So that means that you'll have to issue two queries (one for each table, to [get all the collection docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)) and join/combine their results in your front end.

Another approach would be to duplicate your data (which is quite common in NoSQL world) and create a third collection that contains copies of all the documents.

For this last approach you could use a [Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes) as follows (in Javascript):

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

var docData = {email: 'test@gmail.com', fullname: 'John Doe'}

// Set the value of doc in users collection
var usersRef = db.collection('users').doc();
batch.set(usersRef, docData);

// Set the value of doc in the allUsers collection (i.e. the third collection)
var allUsersRef = db.collection('allUsers').doc();
batch.set(allUsersRef, docData);

// Commit the batch
return batch.commit().then(function () {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, can you please tell on how to create duplicate of data in Firestore?

Comment: There are several possibilities: 1/ You can write to the third collection from your front-end when you write to the `users` or `users_2` collection by using a batch write (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes). 2/ You could use a Cloud Function that would create a copy of the doc in the third collection each time you create a doc in one of the two "main" `users` or `users_2` collections (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0). It depends on your exact needs and app architecture...

Comment: @ShubhamBisht I've just added an example with a Batched write

Comment: Thank you Renaud Tarnec